# How to mount a USB so that it appear in df output?

Tags: usb, mount, devices, df

When a USB `/dev/sdb1` is mounted automatically on `/media/DE61A-1D8C`  , I find it in `df` output.

```
# df
Filesystem     #K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
[...]
/dev/sdb1        1234556    123456   123456   #% /media/DE61A-1D8C
```

It is not the case when the USB is mounted manually with

```
mount /dev/sdb1  /media/DE61A-1D8C
```

**How can I manually mount my USB so that it appear in `df` output?**

---

PS: I am particularly attached in the command

```
watch -n 0.1 df
```